# Use AppID SDK in Objective-C Apps?

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-appid

I tried to install the SDK with CocoaPods in an Objective-C App. The pod install is working, but when I open the workspace, xcode wants to convert the SDK to a newer swift version (which fails).

Is it possible to use the SDK with Objective-C based Apps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can't reproduce this behavior (e.g. XCode does not ask to convert to the new Swift version), but anyway App ID SDK does not support Objective-C, because its classes are not derived from NSObject and are not visible from Objective-C.